# Create a line from two given points

Tags: swift, mapkit, swift3, xcode8, mkpolyline

I am currently working with swift 3 - xcode.

I have a viewcontroller with a map.

I have had annotations to the map, so when I longpress the map I add an annotation like this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

let longPressRec = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longpress(gestureRecognizer:)))

        longPressRec.minimumPressDuration = 1.5   //time for pressing : seconds

        map.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRec)
}
```

to add annotations:

```
func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){


    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)

    let coord = map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)




    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = coord

    annotation.title = "Point X"

    map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print(coord.latitude)
    print(coord.longitude)

    var lastLocation = locationManager.location!       //last location
    var currentLocation = locationManager.location!     //current location


    if locationSet == false {

        let firstLocation = locationManager.location!  //first point

        locationSet = true

    }

    else {  //after second point

        let currentLocation: CLLocation = locationManager.location!

        var locations = [lastLocation, currentLocation]
        var coordinates = locations.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate})


        var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: locations.count)
        map.add(polyline)



    }









}
```

The mapview:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    //if overlay is MKPolyline {
        print("Generating Polyline")
        var renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        renderer.lineWidth = 4
        return renderer

   // }

}
```

Now I'd like, to draw a line, in the map, between second annotion and first annotation, every time I long press the map.

How can I do that?

EDIT: I've tried to do this buts I am not being able. THis is what I have so far...

Comment: What if you long tap your map 3 times? Do you want to draw a line between the second and the third point instead?

Comment: There are 50 different ways to do this. How about you try to figure it out yourself and when you fail, show us your code.

Comment: If I tap, let's say, 5 times, it should make 4 lines: tap 1  to 2, tap 2 to 3, tap 3 to 4, tap 4 to 5. Like a path... I am trying to do it but whithout success

Comment: Sethmr I understand that for many programmers this may be an easy task however for some young programmers like myself it's not... So I am struggling to make this.... thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw the line you implement the mapViewDelegate method:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyLine!)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        renderer.lineWidth = 1
        return renderer
    }
```

To convert your touch point into coordinates to construct your MKPolyLine you use:

```
    mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
```

Comment: Can you give some more help please. I don't really know how to implement that... I'd be so gratefull. I mean I tried adding this code but whithout any success

Comment: I am kind of stuck here. Can someone help? Please